# How do I get the same screen arrangement that windows Display has in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, winapi, screen-resolution, multiple-monitors

I'm trying the following code:

```
foreach (var screen in Screen.AllScreens)
{
    // For each screen, add the screen properties to a list box.
    Console.WriteLine("Device Name: " + screen.DeviceName);
    Console.WriteLine("Bounds: " + screen.Bounds.ToString());
    Console.WriteLine("Working Area: " + screen.WorkingArea.ToString());
    Console.WriteLine("Primary Screen: " + screen.Primary.ToString());
    Console.WriteLine("=====================================================");
}
```

And I get this:

```
Device Name: \\.\DISPLAY1
Bounds: {X=3840,Y=0,Width=3840,Height=2160}
Working Area: {X=3840,Y=0,Width=3840,Height=2120}
Primary Screen: False
=====================================================
Device Name: \\.\DISPLAY2
Bounds: {X=-3840,Y=0,Width=3840,Height=2160}
Working Area: {X=-3840,Y=0,Width=3840,Height=2120}
Primary Screen: False
=====================================================
Device Name: \\.\DISPLAY3
Bounds: {X=0,Y=0,Width=3840,Height=2160}
Working Area: {X=0,Y=0,Width=3840,Height=2120}
Primary Screen: True
=====================================================
```

Which is cool, but the values don't seem to match. This is my current arrangement. Notice that Display 2 is the primary monitor. However, the C# code shows Display 3 as primary, which is wrong.

[image]

I assume there must be a bug in the Screen class (using .NET 4.8, Windows 10), so what is a better way to get the screen position, bounds, arrangement and primary/secondary just like the Display panel does?

Any ideas welcome, thanks!

Comment: `AllScreens` gets its list from [`EnumDisplayMonitors()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-enumdisplaymonitors), which doesn't lie. But device names and ordering are arbitrary. The list is not guaranteed to match the order you see in the Display applet. But what you see for the Primary monitor is accurate, since the primary monitor is always located at 0,0 in the [Virtual Screen](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdi/the-virtual-screen)

Answer (score 0):

WorkingArea X and Y give you the monitor coordinates and then with a little two-dimensional cartesian plane calculation you can figure monitor positions.

Comment: Hello! Thanks for submitting an answer to my question :). I'm a bit confused about the 2D calculation, can you please edit your answer and provide some sample code (or guidance, a formula, anything) so I can test it and mark your answer as valid? Thanks!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `WorkingArea` property of the screen. Then just sort by value:

```
   var screens = Screen.AllScreens;
   screens = screens.OrderBy(o => o.WorkingArea.X).ToArray();
```

then you get the screens sorted from left to right as you see them in windows display setup.

this assumes that you want to sort the screens horizontally. Please note that screens could also be sorted vertically, then you need to adjust the logic accordingly.